# Restored my mac, lost a gesture

Tags: macbook-pro, trackpad, gesture

I used to have a gesture where I could place 2 fingers on the top bar of an application/a file  and use a third finger to drag it around. What gesture is this?

Comment: I think a one-finger click and drag will do, I don't think what you said is a real gesture.

Comment: @owlswipe I found it. Its not a "gesture" per se, but an accessibility option. Settings -> accessibility -> Mouse/trackpad -> trackpad options -> enable dragging -> 3 finger drag

Comment: @Programatic Ah ok. Nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. It's not a gesture but an Accessibility feature. Navigate to the screenshot shown below (`System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > Trackpad Options...`) and you can enable dragging from there.

[image]

Switch it to `three finger drag` and your lost functionality will be restored.

[image]